# Powershell - detect whether running in interactive mode or not

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to detect from a powershell profile whether powershell has been invoked interactively or not? I see some people using `$host.name` but it seems to always return `ConsoleHost`.

Comment: i THINK  you can do it with this >>> `[System.Environment]::UserInteractive` <<<

Comment: You may want to check out this question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738535/powershell-test-for-noninteractive-mode

Comment: @Lee_Daily, that seems to always return `True` for me, either from a script `pwsh -noni test.ps1` or in a command block: `pwsh -noni -c '[System.Environment]::UserInteractive`.

Comment: @Dallas thanks that's probably as good as I'm going to get. Too bad there's not a better way than checking the flags on the process...

Comment: It looks like `[System.Environment]::UserInteractive` is [not referring to an interactive shell exactly...](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/770) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/1234/files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple method to put in your $PROFILE that works as long as the calling process passes the -NonInteractive parameter. It may not work with everything but, as Dallas mentioned above, there are other more complex methods on [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738535/powershell-test-for-noninteractive-mode).

```
if ([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs().Contains('-NonInteractive')) {
    $Global:InteractiveMode=$false
} else {
    $Global:InteractiveMode=$true
}
```

You can then use that variable in your scripts to do something like [removing color codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65735639/powershell-disable-colored-command-output) from batch job output.

```
if (-not $InteractiveMode) {
    # For PWSH 7.2+
    $PSStyle.OutputRendering = [System.Management.Automation.OutputRendering]::PlainText
}
```

Comment: I don't really see any relation of most of the answer to detecting interactive mode. Please specifically answer the question without too much "noise".

Comment: but users can pass case-insensirive shortened options such as `-nonI`, `-Nonint`... which this will fail to check. The other linked answer uses `$_ -like '-NonI*'` which is far better